# Extrair Arquivos Especificos com C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows

Boa Tarde Pessoal,

Tenho uma duvida e espero que vocês possam me ajudar.

Adicionei ao meu projeto, um arquivo ZIP com arquivos dentro.
Preciso compilar esse arquivo zip junto com o programa.
Depois de compilado o programa, ao clicar em um botão, o programa extrairá os arquivos que estão dentro do arquivo ZIP em uma pasta especifica.

Gostaria de saber qual código utilizar para realizar tal processo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde Andrey
O que eu faria nesse caso:

1. Renomearia o arquivo .zip para outra extensão. (Ex. .data, .bin, etc...)
2. Alteraria a propriedade "Copy to Output Directory" para "Copy Always", com isso o arquivo sempre irá para o seu diretório de output na hora do build e do publish
3. Agora sua aplicação pode descompactar o arquivo utilizando a classe System.IO.Compression.ZipFile(https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netframework-4.8).

Obs. Não tenho certeza de que a classe ZipFile consegue descompactar arquivos com outra extensão que não seja .zip. Caso tenha problema com isso, é só renomear o arquivo utilizando System.IO.File.Move (https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=netframework-4.8)

Isso pode parecer uma gambiarra, mas não é uma prática tão incomum, afinal os próprios arquivos do nuget são .zip com outra extensão.